# React "map" is undefined/empy while there is a state array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a weird problem when I console log my component on load to check if there is a state. I Get an array back with data. But when I try to loop through it. I get map undefined? I don't understand why it's driving me crazy.

What am i doing wrong? I used the same thing on other components without any problems.

Thanks!

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

// API settings
import { WP_DATA_URL } from 'constants/import';

// Axios fetching
import axios from 'axios';

// components
import Youtube from 'components/Youtube/Youtube';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import SpinnerLoader from 'components/SpinnerLoader/SpinnerLoader';

class College extends Component {
    state = {
        page_college: [],
        loading: true,
    };

    getCoffee() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve('☕'), 1000); // it takes half of a second to make coffee
        });
    }

    async showData() {
        try {
            const wpCollege = axios(`${WP_DATA_URL}/pages?slug=college`);

            await this.getCoffee();

            await Promise.all([wpCollege]).then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    page_college: response[0].data[0].acf,
                    loading: false,
                });

                console.log(this.state.page_college);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e); // 
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.showData();
    }

    render() {
        const { loading } = this.state;
        const { title, description, page_college: college } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="pages--container">
                <div className="pages">
                    <div className="row center-xs pages--wrapper">
                        <div className="page">
                            <div className="page--content">
                                {loading ? (
                                    <SpinnerLoader />
                                ) : (
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                                            <h2>HOI</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                        {college.map(data => {
                                            console.log(data);
                                        })}
                                        </div>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default College;
```

Comment: What is `response[0].data[0].acf`? Is it an array?

Comment: can you tell console.log of this  -->  `console.log(typeof college)` ? I think you missing parsing JSON.

Comment: I'm wondering if `response[0].data[0].acf` is coming back as `undefined`? Logging after `setState` is not reliable since `setState` is asynchronous and you may be logging the _old_ state and not the updated state

Comment: Thank you guys i was not inside an array.

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous so your `console.log` after it may be reflecting the previous state. Pass `setState` a callback as the 2nd param and check the state there. `response[0].data[0].acf` might not be an array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
async componentDidMount() {
        await this.showData();
    }
```

Just make the componentDidMount wait for the showData to complete.